# Preparing JSON for MongoDB import

Tags: json, mongodb, express, mongoimport

It's my understanding that in order to import JSON into MongoDB *mongoimport* requires one JSON string per line. Is there any tool that converts a normal JSON document into this format?

Comment: What format do you currently have?

Comment: yes please post example of the JSON you are working with

Comment: I've not created the content yet, so it can be any format I want.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is use regular expression, many txt editor support RE, to find line break you can use "\r\n" or "\n" expressions, NotePad++ on windows env supports it and I just tested it successfully.

You can create a simple utility to remove it too using regex or in the following link you can see discussion about some find/replace regex based tools, including linux command line: [Looking for a lightweight regex find and replace tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713053/looking-for-a-lightweight-regex-find-and-replace-tool)

Regards,
Moacy

Answer (score 0):

- You can use This Command in command prompt to import JSON FIle

```
mongoimport -d tymongo -c test --type csv --file database2.csv --headerline
```

- where d- database(tymongo-database name), c-collection(test-collection name)